# How to fix this Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Tags: vb6

List item

How to fix this error" Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"?

This for the adding and display stored data in listview in vb6

```
 Dim connect As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim a As Integer
  Dim b As Integer
  Dim x As Long
  Dim c As String
 Option Explicit

  Private Sub Command1_Click()
    rs.AddNew    'this line shows the error
    ado.Recordset.Fields("EMPID").Value = emp.Text
    ado.Recordset.Fields("DEPARTMENT") = Text2.Text
    ado.Recordset.Fields("EMPNAME") = Text1.Text
    ado.Recordset.Fields("TIMEIN") = DTPicker3.Value
    ado.Recordset.Fields("TIMEOUT") = DTPicker4.Value
    ado.Recordset.Fields("LOGDATE") = DTPicker2.Value
    rs.Update

  End Sub

     Private Sub Command2_Click()
           a = DateDiff("d", DTPicker1, DTPicker2)
     b = DateDiff("h", DTPicker3, DTPicker4)

     x = a * b
     c = x * 52.5
     Text7.Text = "Hours:" & x & " Days:" & a & "$ " & c
     End Sub

     Private Sub Form_Load()
      connect.Open _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source=C:\Users\MIS02\Desktop\FILE.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"


    With ListView1.ColumnHeaders
    .Add , , "EMPID", Width / 15, lvwColumnLeft
    .Add , , "DEPARTMENT", Width / 10, lvwColumnCenter
    .Add , , "EMPNAME", Width / 12, lvwColumnCenter
    .Add , , "TIMEIN", Width / 12, lvwColumnCenter
    .Add , , "TIMEOUT", Width / 12, lvwColumnCenter
    .Add , , "LOGDATE", Width / 10, lvwColumnCenter
    End With

      End Sub

Sub dbconnection()
connect.Open _
  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data         
  Source=C:\Users\MIS02\Desktop\FILE.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"

      End Sub
     Sub loaddata()
      Dim list As ListItem
      ListView1.ListItems.Clear
      dbconnection
            rs.Open "Select *from Attendance", con, adOpenDynamic,                  
   adLockOptimistic

      Do Until rs.EOF
      Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs!Employee)
      list.SubItems(1) = rs!Department
      list.SubItems(2) = rs!Surename
      list.SubItems(3) = rs!FirstName
      list.SubItems(4) = rs!TimeIn
        list.Subitems(5)=rs!Timeout
      list.SubItems(6) = rs!DateRecord
      rs.MoveNext


Loop
```

=======================================================

I expect that i can store and display data in listview.

Comment: The recordset `rs` appears to be opened in the sub `loaddata`. But `loaddata` isn't called anywhere in the posted code, so I would expect an "object closed" error when you try to call `rs.AddNew`.

Comment: And those `ado.Recordset.Fields` references will be causing you problems next. I expect you intend to add those column values to the new record just added to recordset `rs`? So do so: `rs.Fields("blahblah")`.

Comment: Hi good day, Thank you for your response i put the loaddata in form load but theres another error in in my dbconnection same error

Comment: You are opening the connection object `connect` twice, it's inefficient but that shouldn't throw an exception. The `rs.open` call is using `con` which is not defined, created or opened in the posted code - I'd expect that could throw an exception or compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `connect` as a connection and seems like you tend to use it (since you're calling `dbconnection` method). But at the same time you pass `con` as a parameter for opening your recordset. Probably this variable either not exists or if exists on a global level - not initialized/opened correctly.